# Como recupero uma linha na minha jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Gostaria de saber como recupero a informação de uma linha de minha `JTable`, segue a linha de códigos da mesma.

```
Usuarios operacao = new Usuarios();
DefaultTableModel tabela = new DefaultTableModel();

private void adicionarLinhas(String nome, String patente, String sessao, String email) {
    this.tabela.addRow(new Object[]{nome, patente, sessao, email});
}

public void Executar() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<UsuariosBase> usuarios2 = operacao.LeituraDeRegistros();
    for (UsuariosBase registros : usuarios2) {
        tabela = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        this.adicionarLinhas(registros.nome, registros.patente, registros.sessao, registros.email);
    }
}

public void Listar() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    operacao.RecuperadorDeNomes();
    for (int i = 1; i < operacao.totalDeArquivos; i++) {
        Executar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar [**`getValueAt`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)):

```
suaJTable.getModel().getValueAt(indiceLinha, indiceColuna);
```

O código não faz muito sentido da forma como foi apresentado, pois essa variável `tabela` está iniciando um `DefaultTableModel` vazio, dependendo do momento em que você chamar esse método, ele pode retornar vazio. Mas caso você garanta que esta variável corresponderá ao model já aplicado na sua JTable, basta chamar o método por ela:

```
tabela.getValueAt(indiceLinha, indiceColuna);
```

Lembrando que colunas e linhas sempre começam no indice 0, portanto, uma tabela com 15 linhas terá indices de 0 a 14.

Para varrer uma linha selecionada e pegar todas as colunas, pode-se fazer desta forma:

```
int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int columnCount = suaJTable.getColumnCount();

for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
    //aqui você faz alguma coisa com o dado de cada coluna
    System.out.println(tabela.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, i);)
}
```

Comment: Tentei aplicar o código mas recebi um erro: " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 ", criei uma operação: " public void Recupera() {
        int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        int columnCount = jTable1.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            System.out.println(tabela.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, i));
        }
    } " e apliquei na inicialização da classe, sabe em que errei?

Comment: @netoschneider adicione  um **[mcve]** editando a pergunta, sem isso não tem como testar e ver o que poderia causar o erro.

Comment: Já resolvi meu grande, eu esqueci que estava utilizando um for para multiplicar as ações do Executor do método para adicionar linhas a jTable, agora está 100% funcionando, você sabe me dizer como eu faço o clique do mouse corresponder a determinado item da tabela? Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @netoschneider se o problema te ajudou, você pode marcar como aceita a resposta, clicando no `v` ao lado esquerdo dela, desta forma, ela servirá de referencia para duvidas semelhante a sua :)

Comment: @netoschneider getseletedrow já pega a linha selecionada, não entendi sua outra duvida.

Comment: Gostaria de saber como eu faço para o programa identificar o clique do mouse para assim passar a seleção a ação de captura de linha.

Comment: Já solucionei, muito obrigado!